# Prime number sum ,Though not really easy

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, primes

Given a number `n` and integer `k`, check whether k prime number sums to `n` or not.

```
input 13 2
output: yes
explanation: 11+2 equals 13
```

since k is assumed to be any general integer, I don't know how to solve it. I thought to solve it by creating set of all prime number and looking for k number but even if k is as small as 5 we have to run 4 to 5 loop to do it. how to approach such problem, kindly looking for help,thanks.
I tried initial code as:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool is_prime(int n){
    bool flag =true;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
        if(n%i==0 && n!=i){
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main(){
    int n;cin>>n;
    int k;cin>>k;
    unordered_set<int>s;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
        if(is_prime(i)){
            s.insert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which are the ranges of `n` and `k`?

Comment: @jarod42 nothing was mentioned, consider integer range in general

Comment: So brute-force, or even `O(N+K)` seems out of consideration. Have to find a mathematical formula.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved by assuming [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture). Goldbach's conjecture says:

> Any even integer is the sum of two prime numbers

We can exploit this to create the following rules:

1. If `n < 2k` then NO (because 2 is the smallest prime)
2. If `k == 1` then YES IFF n is prime
3. If `n >= 2k` and `k == 2` THEN YES if n is even (Goldbach) , If n is odd then NO iff n-2 is not a prime number
4. If `n >= 2k` and `k >= 3` THEN Always YES:

   - When `n` is even, it can be expressed as `2 + ... + 2 + (n - 2 * (k - 2))`,
     `n - 2 * (k - 2)` is also even and can be expressed as a sum of two primes (by Goldbach),
   - When `n` is odd, it can be expresses as `3 + 2 + ... + 2 + (n - 3 - 2 * (k - 3))`,
     `n - 3 - 2 * (k - 3)` is even and can be expressed by sum of two primes (Goldbach).

Comment: Goldbach's conjecture is still a conjecture because it is yet to be proven. Creating an algorithm based on it might not be a wise move even if the [verified results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Verified_results) are sufficient for the purpose.

Comment: @PalLaden - Well, if the algorithm fails, the OP has just found a counter-example to the Goldbach conjecture. That's a $1M prize or two right there. There's really no down-side.

Comment: @PalLaden it is proven for all integers less than ```4×10^18```, so for practical purposes it can be considered proven because that range is ```10^9``` larger than the range of C++ int

Comment: @christian sloper your approach seems visionary and you deduced it in a couple of minutes as well, It made me wonder, Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @BrettHale The problem is, the OP doesn't know the algorithm fails when it actually fails...